# Focus when change to TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have window with `TabControl` and four `TabItem`s. And I need to change focus to right `textBox` when tab is selected. Is here some right way to do it?
I tried to use `TabControl_SelectionChanged` event, but it looks like it doesn't work.

```
 private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (((TabItem)((TabControl)sender).SelectedItem).Name == "tab2")
     {
         UpdateLayout();
         textBox2EAN.Focus();
     }
     e.Handled = true;
 }
```

But if I click on tab2 focus is on `DataGrids`'s checkbox column.

TabItem: ...

```
<TabItem Name="tab2" Header="2" Width="50">
  <Grid>    
      <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" Margin="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MouseDoubleClick="dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RadkyDokladu.radky}" CanUserSortColumns="False" PreviewKeyDown="dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="12" SelectionMode="Single" >
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding ZASKRTNUTO}" Width="auto" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Náz" Binding="{Binding Artikl_NAME}" Width="*"/>
          </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
      <TextBox Name="textBox2EAN" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="1" 
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
  </Grid>
</Tabitem>
```

Comment: Is the method correctly added to the TabControl.SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: Im using `<TabControl SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged">`

Comment: Does the textBox even get the focus before it jumps to the checkbox?

Comment: Event is fired and code get to `textBox2EAN.Focus();`.. but at the end `checkBox` column is focused (it's first thing in order). I guess the focus is called before actual tab change is execute so it it ends to focus the first thing in `TabItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just move it to XAML and let the controls inside the TabItem move focus when they are ready:

```
<TabItem Name="tab2" Header="2" Width="50">
    <Grid FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=textBox2EAN}">
       <DataGrid />
       <TextBox Name="textBox2EAN" />
   </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this before and didn't work... So i tried one more time and it looks promising.. thanks again

Comment: @Sk1X1, no problem. If you don't have some focus switching in code, then it should work.